# Why aren't my thread locks working properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

For an assignment, I'm supposed to create a simple multi-threaded program that has three threads that wait for a random amount of time (between .1 and 2 seconds) and then print "end." I'm trying to use locks to prevent switching from messing up the output, but my output is still seemingly random (meaning the locks aren't working as intended).
My code is:

```
import time
from threading import *
import random

lock = Lock()

def one():
    global lock
    time.sleep((random.randint(1,20))/10)
    lock.acquire()
    print("1. end")
    lock.release()

def two():
    global lock
    time.sleep((random.randint(1,20))/10)
    lock.acquire()
    print("2. end")
    lock.release()

def three():
    global lock
    time.sleep((random.randint(1,20))/10)
    lock.acquire()
    print("3. end")
    lock.release()


for i in range(0,100):
    t1 = Thread(target = one)
    t2 = Thread(target = two)
    t3 = Thread(target = three)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```

but my output is:

```
 2. end
 3. end
 1. end
 3. end
 2. end
 2. end
 1. end
 3. end
 1. end
 etc...
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is switching messing up the output? You should be getting prints in groups of 3, of any combination of 1,2,3. I assume that the output you show is just somewhere in the middle of what is scrolling by on the screen. This is the proper way to lock if you want to avoid garbled output like "1. 2. eendnd" where multiple threads are calling print at the same time.

Comment: As an aside, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You acquire the lock after random sleep :

```
import time
from threading import *
import random

lock = Lock()

def one():
    global lock
    lock.acquire()
    time.sleep((random.randint(1,20))/10)
    print("1. end")
    lock.release()

def two():
    global lock
    lock.acquire()
    time.sleep((random.randint(1,20))/10)
    print("2. end")
    lock.release()

def three():
    global lock
    lock.acquire()
    time.sleep((random.randint(1,20))/10)
    print("3. end")
    lock.release()


for i in range(0,100):
    t1 = Thread(target = one)
    t2 = Thread(target = two)
    t3 = Thread(target = three)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```

Comment: This will randomly block all threads based on which one happens to get to the lock first. I don't see how this fixes anything.